# Space ship makes everybody on Earth lose one day of memory each day

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is what I remember from this story I read about 40 years ago.

There is a space ship above Earth. At the end of every day, it causes everybody to completely lose the memory of what they did that day. And this effect got even worse every day because every next day they lose a day more of their memory, so for instance after the week the space ship arrived they not only forgot everything they did that week, they also forgot everything they did the week before the space ship arrived.

The humans plan to destroy the space ship. Because they forget everything each day, they have to write down everything they discovered about how to destroy the space ship.

After some years some of the younger humans lose their ability to read, so they cannot read the planning anymore, after many years even the oldest humans working at the project can only write like children, but they are finally able to destroy the space ship.

Comment: And of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96811/story-of-a-large-alien-artifact-that-erases-memory?rq=1

Comment: Not a terribly close match, but similar themes.

Comment: You're right! My mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Phillip Jose Farmer's ["Sketches Among the Ruins of My Mind"](http://www.pjfarmer.com/WORKS-stories.html) as per *[Alien probe scans memories and causes (daily) world mind wipe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73797/alien-probe-scans-memories-and-causes-daily-world-mind-wipe/73816#73816)*

> A space ship arrives in our solar system and time starts going
> backwards. People wake up thinking its Wednesday but it is really
> Sunday and they had no memory of the last four days. The next day is
> worse as the same thing happens and they lose four more days. This
> goes on and on as grown people start drooling like babies and are
> unable to take care of themselves. How do the world governments deal
> with the problem and what are the long term affects on society?

Comment: What's the source of the quote (it's a quote in the source answer) and can it be corrected?

Comment: @davidw: I copied it from Farmer's sure, which I linked.

Comment: Oh, good grief, all those grammatical and spelling errors are there in a page billing itself as the official website of an author.